# threatened loss of, "threatened" modifying "loss"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, expressions, sentence

In the sentence

> The threatened loss of specific tastes and the local cultures that produce them animate this movement.

is "threatened" modifying "loss"?

I thought that analyzing it so was wrong, as I thought what the sentence was trying to say was that "specific tastes" were under threat, not the "loss" itself. Though in this way, I don't see what "threatened" is supposed to modify...

Comment: "The threatened loss of X" means "the possibility that X will be lost".

Comment: Or even, the *threat* (which is threatened) is that "X will be lost". Or even, "X is 'under threat'". Analysing *threatened* here is ... interesting.

Comment: By default, an adjective (including Past Participle used adjectivally) applies to the immediately-following noun, so in your case it's the ***loss*** which is characterised as "threatened" (there's a risk that the loss may in fact materialise). If the writer intended it to apply to ***specific tastes*** he'd have written *The loss of **threatened** specific tastes* (more idiomatically, perhaps, *The loss of specific tastes [which were] **under threat.***

Comment: 'threatened' modifies the whole string 'loss of [specific tastes and the local cultures that produce them]'.

Comment: "threatened loss of specific tastes"  sounds like a medical condition.